# ASP.NET Can't set value to datepicker from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker, setvalue

I have a datepicker field

```
$(function () {
        $("#dateTextBox").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

        $("#dateTextBox").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});
```

In code behind, on button click, I'm trying to set value to datepicker field:

```
dateTextBox.Value = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

But after postback, textbox is empty...

Comment: Try to set the datetime format on the datepicker plugin same as the one from server side `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Just tried, not working.

Comment: If you chose a date from the picker, what format does it have? Maybe you need to set the culture, the default US is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: I don't have problem reading from datepicker field, but setting it...
Format is set as 
$("#dateTextBox").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you need to read details from client side using hidden field. This hiddenfield value can be set at server side.

For example:

create hidden field on page

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnDate" runat="server" />
```

set date string in hiddenField :

```
protected void button_Clicked (...)
{
     DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
     hdnDate.Value = dt.Year.ToString() + "," + (dt.Month - 1 ).ToString() + "," + dt.Day.ToString();
}
```

now, on document.ready of jquery event, do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dateTextBox").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

  dtString = $("#<%=hdnDate.ClientID%>").val();
  dtString = dtString.split(',');
  var defaultDate = new Date(dtString[0], dtString[1], dtString[2]);
  $("#dateTextBox").datepicker("setDate",defaultDate);

});
```

Comment: I'll try asap, but could you explain to me why is it such a complicated process?

Comment: Datepicker control that you are using is a javascript control. In ASP.net webpage life cycle, code behind runs first then it executes HTML / javascript part. Your datepicker control is being generated in HTML part. so you can't set a value for the control which is not generated yet.

Comment: Works, but increments my month by 1... Any clue?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code and checking the value what is stored in HiddenField ? is the month being incremented by code behind or the script  ?

Comment: datepicker("setDate") is incrementing

Comment: Copy paste of yours... Plus the one given in the question.
dtString[1] contains correct value.

Comment: Are you sure, datepicker's date format is correct ? is it mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?   what is date value that you are setting to datePicker ?

If it is formatting issue, try this line at the end of your script:
$("#dateTextBox").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");

Comment: I added, below the code in the question:
var dtString = $("#<%=hdnDate.ClientID%>").val();
            if (dtString !== "") {
                dtString = dtString.split(',');
                var defaultDate = new Date(dtString[0], dtString[1], dtString[2]);
                $("#dateTextBox").datepicker("setDate", defaultDate);
            }

Comment: I don't see any issue with the jquery. 

what about the code behind ? did you set correct value in hiddenfield through codebehind? 

One question - what date value you are expecting and what is being displayed ?

Comment: Months start at 0 index... That's why its incremented. Update in your answer and I'll mark as accepted

Comment: I see I wasn't clear enough in my last comment...
So (dt.Month - 1).ToString() is needed...

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dateTextBox.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```