# ASP.NET Can't set value to datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker, setvalue

I read the post [ASP.NET Can't set value to datepicker from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728434/asp-net-cant-set-value-to-datepicker-from-code-behind) and tried to follow but I see date as NaN/NaN/NaN. Here is my jQuery DatePicker and asp.net code.

```
<script>
$(function () {

$('#txtDate').datepicker({ 

onSelect: function() { if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function')Page_ClientValidate($(this).attr('txtDate'));}}).datepicker("setDate" )   
$("#txtDate").datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: '1920:2030',
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
onSelect: function() { if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate();}
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
var dtString = $("#<%=hdnDate.ClientID%>").val();
if(dtString !== ""){
var defaultDate = new Date(dtString[0], dtString[1], dtString[2]);
$("#txtDate").datepicker("setDate", defaultDate);
}
});
</script>
```

Here is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnDate" runat="server" />
```

I populate the value of hdnDate field when user clicks on any date. When I view source code of the page, I see the following

```
<input name="txtDate" type="text" value="NaN/NaN/NaN" id="txtDate" style="width:150px;" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnDate" id="hdnDate" value="10/20/2015" />
```

Am I doing something wrong with my jQuery code?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

This is the line to blame:

```
var defaultDate = new Date(dtString[0], dtString[1], dtString[2]);
```

When the hidden field contains the value of `10/20/2015`, this looks like

```
var defaultDate = new Date("1", "0", "/");
```

None of these are integers, and even if conversion happens, these are not valid values for year, month and day (as expected for this signature).

Consider passing date as a whole instead:

```
var defaultDate = new Date(dtString);
```

As long as `Date.parse` can recognize and parse your format, this should work correctly.

Comment: var defaultDate = new Date(dtString); workes only in Firefox and Chrome, IE shows as today's date now in Edge mode where as in view source shows <input name="txtDate" type="text" value="10/14/2015" id="txtDate" style="width:150px;" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="hdnDate" id="hdnDate" value="10/20/2015" />